# iOS 6 Tab Bar App: shouldAutorotate not working

Tags: ios6, uitabbarcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I momently developing a application with a tab bar and some navigation view controllers in Storyboard using iOS 6 and Xcode 4.5

Usually the app should support all interface orientations but I have two views that only should support portrait mode.

So I added the following code to the view controllers:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

On a other app I developed without storyboard and navigation view controller on iOS 6 it works but her NOT! :/

I hope someone can help, because I found some other post that where not helpful...

With best regards from Germany

Laurenz

**EDIT:**

I also tried - Doesn't work! :

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excellent answer by Jonathan.

I modified his code little bit to handle navigation controller in a single snippet.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    if (self.selectedViewController) {
        if ([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            return [[[(UINavigationController*)self.selectedViewController viewControllers] lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
        }
        return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (self.selectedViewController) {
        if ([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            return [[[(UINavigationController*)self.selectedViewController viewControllers] lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
        }
        return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, this problem arises because the UITabBarController and UINavigationController are returning their own default values for -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate and -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations.

One solution is to extend both of those classes via categories (or just subclass), in order to return the appropriate values from your own implementations of these methods in your view controller. This is what worked for me (you can just drop this into your App Delegate):

```
@implementation UITabBarController(AutorotationFromSelectedView)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    if (self.selectedViewController) {
        return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (self.selectedViewController) {
        return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
}

@end

@implementation UINavigationController(AutorotationFromVisibleView)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    if (self.visibleViewController) {
        return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (self.visibleViewController) {
        return [self.visibleViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
}
@end
```

By default, all your view controllers will continue to autorotate. In the two View Controllers that should only support portrait mode, implement the following:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: I implemented your code in appdelegate.m and in my viewcontroller.m. It is now locking landscape mode of viewcontroller.m but when I come from previous view to viewcontroller.m in landscape mode then it shows the screen in landscape mode and this time it do not change to potrait mode.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Ive been having loads of trouble with this and categorising UITab and UINav fixed it. You should mark this answer as correct.

Comment: I've extended this code to support UISplitViewController too: https://gist.github.com/cameroncooke/a9244bc4d677f50940f5